# The connection has timed out. The server at ### is taking too long to respond

Tags: .net, iis-7

I know this has to be something simple but it is driving me crazy. I have a site running on iis on my local machine that I was just working on a couple of days ago. To my knowledge I have changed nothing. However, when I try to navigate to it now so that I can do some more work I am receiving the above error. I have restarted the site, the app pool and the computer. What in the world might be causing this error?

The default site in iis on this machine is running fine. It is only the site that I have set with a port number. There should be no database data loading when the site first opens other than the typical connection string check.

---

Interesting... I changed the binding and now it works fine. If someone would point me to some documentation that will help explain this to me I would be most grateful and happy to mark it as the answer. Of course, I will Google it but I figure one of you may know of an excellent resource already.

Comment: what do your server logs say?

Comment: Does it conenct to any other computer for data?

Comment: No new server log yet today. I don't see anything out of the ordinary from yesterday though I will admit that I seldom look at them and I am not that familiar with them. Also, no, the computer does not connect to any other computer for data.

Comment: If you showed the binding change then might be able to help

Comment: @Darren I have the same problem at the moment. What did you change the bindings to?

Answer (score 0):

any number of things could be causing this.

1. poor connection/command management
2. poor query indexing
3. retrieving too much data
4. excecution time span

Answer (score 0):

Check your anti-virus software. Specifically check to see if it has something called a "link-scanner" (or along those lines). Try to either whitelist localhost (or whatever dns name you access your IIS through), or disable it altogether. It helped me. I was running AVG-Free.

Comment: One of the first things I did was disable the antivirus software. I appreciate the tip but that did not help.